# What class / method does xtext call when a reference can't be resolved

Tags: xtext

This is regarding the error "Couldn't resolved reference to definition..."
If we have an editor open, and a line is flagged with this error, if we so much as click in the line, we get an hourglass that can stay up for minutes.  I want to look at the code that is being invoked to see if I can insert a timeout.  But, I can't located the class.  Can someone tell me what Xtext class and method is likely being invoked so I can debug the problem.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use a profiler to spot the slow parts of the code. From your vague description, it sounds like the quickfix computation takes very long which would boil down to your scope provider implementation. But again I'd strongly suggest to use a profiler.

Comment: I added a profiler.  When the slow down occurs, the main method consuming the CPU is org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.WorkerPool.sleep().  When I filter for org.eclipse.xtext, the method most consuming the CPU is org.eclipse.xtext.concurrent.ReadWriteAccess.acquireReadLock().  The second method consuming the CPU is org.eclipse.xtext.ui.label.InjectableAdapterFactoryLabelProvider.getText().  I do not have any custom code for labels.